# Any way to automate deleting non-owner of a bidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello Hibernate/JPA gurus!
I am new to Hibernate, and have a question.

Say I have a bidirection relationship between Books and Tags (any book can be tagged with any tag)

```
Tables:
book (bookid, bookname)
tag (tagid, tagname)
booktaglink (booktaglinkid, bookid, tagid)

public class Book() {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.EVICT})
    @JoinTable(name = "booktaglink", 
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bookid") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tagid") })
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList()

}

public class Tag() {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="tags")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.EVICT})
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList()
}
```

So, above... I have Books and Tags bidirectional relationship, so I can retrieve tags that are associated with the book, and books that are associated with the tags.  However, Books owns the relationship.

Say I want to delete a tag.  Is this correct?

```
Tag tagToDelete;
List<Book> books = tag.getBooks()
for (Book book: books) {
  book.getTags().remove(tagToDelete);
  dataSource.save(book)
}
dataSource.delete(tagToDelete);
```

1. Why do I have to open the owner of association (in this case Book class) and remove the tag I am trying to delete?  Can I simply cascade the delete and remove all associations with books?  This sucks because if I simply do dataSource.delete(tagToDelete), it will leave all the associations in the link table, and cause errors.   Is there any way to automate the delete process instead of looping as I did in the example above.
2. Is there a general rule about who should own the relationship?
3. Why would anyone create a uni-directional relationship?  If this was unidirectional, and I am trying to delete a tag, I will never be able to delete the associations except if I loop through all the books in the database and remove the tag I am deleting.  Seems inefficient.

Thanks so much!!
PA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting an entity in a bidirectional `ManyToMany` relation is not that intuitive. From what i recall, when you delete an entity from the owning side (`Book` in your case), all joins are deleted as well without deleting any `Tag`s. Vize versa this won't work. To solve this, just declare both sides as owning sides. Plus I advise you to use `Set`s to prevent duplicate data.

In your class `Tag` get rid of `mappedBy="tags"` and add a `@JoinTable`:

```
@JoinTable(name = "booktaglink", 
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tagid") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bookid") })
private Set<Book> books;
```